# How can redirect all my site links to another domain except "index.php" and some other files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I redirect all the requests to my site to another domain except the file `/index.php` and the file of `/members/` and `/Admins/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your `.htaccess` try the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(members|Admins)/
RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ https://other.example%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This assumes that your "other domain" (eg. `other.example`) points to a different server.